# How to create Recycler View with checkboxes

Tags: android, list, checkbox, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I want to create a `RecyclerView` with a list of options with `check boxes`. There must be buttons **Select All** and **Deselect All** to select and deselect all `check boxes` in the `RecyclerView`. Individual check box selection also need to be there.

[image]

Can any one help me ???

Thanks in advance